# clicking on a image submits the form by default?

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, forms, image

I didn't realize this, and just want to confirm.

If I have a html form, and an input tag of type image like:

```
<input type="image" name="blah" src="..." />
```

Clicking on the image will submit the form?

My use case is, I want to create a custom button for a submit button.

Comment: Seriously, did you try to do what you're asking about before asking?  Do you even recognize that you're now not only looking at documentation before asking questions, you're plain not even trying to run your own code before asking questions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, input-images will submit the form naturally. See: http://w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp

> *image*: Defines an image as a submit button